# Docker container cannot see broker on port 1883 on host (Windows 10)

Tags: windows

I have an MQTT broker (mosquitto) running in Windows 10.  It is tested and fully working on 127.0.0.1. I have a Docker container of the Chirpstack Gateway Bridge.  It attempts to connect to the broker through port 1883, but always fails.  I should see it failing to connect in the log of the broker but nothing appears there. The same error occurs "connection refused" even when the broker is turned off.  I suspect the container is not getting outside of itself to communicate with port 1883 on the host.  Your thoughts?

```
PS C:\BRIDGE> docker compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 - Container bridge-lora-bridge-1  Created                                                                                                                      0.0s
Attaching to bridge-lora-bridge-1
bridge-lora-bridge-1  | INFO[0000] starting ChirpStack Gateway Bridge            docs="https://www.chirpstack.io/gateway-bridge/" version=
bridge-lora-bridge-1  | INFO[0000] backend/semtechudp: starting gateway udp listener  addr="0.0.0.0:1700"
bridge-lora-bridge-1  | ERRO[0000] [client]   dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1883: connect: connection refused  module=mqtt
bridge-lora-bridge-1  | WARN[0000] [client]   failed to connect to broker, trying next  module=mqtt
bridge-lora-bridge-1  | ERRO[0000] [client]   Failed to connect to a broker      module=mqtt
bridge-lora-bridge-1  | FATA[0000] network Error : dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1883: connect: connection refused
bridge-lora-bridge-1 exited with code 1
```

Contents to docker-composer.yml

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  lora-bridge:
    image: chirpstack/chirpstack-gateway-bridge
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true  # docker run -t
    privileged: true
    volumes: 
      - C:\BRIDGE\.config:/etc/chirpstack-gateway-bridge/
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 1700:1700
```